# Bedeutung von "über den Hunger hinaus gegessen"

Tags: meaning

> In Ländern mit reichlichem Nahrungsangebot haben die meisten schon einmal weit **über den Hunger hinaus gegessen**.

Vielleicht handelt sich um eine ganze Reihe von Verben, die nach ähnlichem Muster verwendet werden, denn die Kombination aus "über etwas hinaus" habe ich schon mehrmals gesehen.

Comment: Richtig wäre *hinaus gegessen*, da sich *hinaus* auf den Hunger, nicht aber auf das Essen bezieht. Da Essen ein Prozess ist, bei dem etwas _eingenommen_ wird, wirkt die Zusammenschreibung irreführend oder komisch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ich habe Hunger. Ich möchte den Hunger stillen und esse daher. Wenn dann aber der Hunger gestillt ist, besteht eigentlich kein vernünftiger Grund mehr, weiter zu essen. Wer aber trotzdem, obwohl der Hunger schon gestillt ist, noch immer weiter isst, der isst über den Hunger hinaus. Und wer das exzessiv macht, der isst sogar *weit* über den Hunger hinaus.

Die Phrase

> über etwas hinaus

bedeutet, dass man etwas weiter macht, obwohl das eigentliche Ziel längst erreicht ist.

Comment: Es gibt ja auch den Ausdruck "einen über den Durst trinken".